# Not able to uninstall Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have tried the command "/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command" but it seems to be there is no Jenkins folder inside Application support.

hotty@Bikashs-MacBook-Air Downloads % /Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command
zsh: no such file or directory: /Library/Application

How to uninstall Jenkins now?

Comment: Why are you sure Jenkins is installed on your computer properly?

Comment: Because in Port 8080 it is showing Jenkins dash bord but when I am trying to create a new project it is opening a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

A MAC comes with Unix-like OS. Just delete the entire Jenkins Directory. That should fix it.

Also, noticed that you are on zsh you need to switch to bash/sh for that to work I think.

Use `chsh -s /bin/bash` to change shell and see if you can execute that command again.

Make sure you delete the .jenkins directory under your home directory